# Does C++ do value initialization of a POD typedef?

Tags: c++, pointers

Does C++ do value initialization on simple [POD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146452/) typedefs?

Assuming

```
typedef T* Ptr;
```

does

```
Ptr()
```

do value-initialization and guarantee to equal `(T*)0`?

e.g.

```
Ptr p = Ptr();
return Ptr();
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It does. For a type `T`, `T()` value-initializes an "object" of type `T` and yields an rvalue expression.

```
int a = int();
assert(a == 0);
```

Same for pod-classes:

```
struct A { int a; };
assert(A().a == 0);
```

Also true for some non-POD classes that have no user declared constructor:

```
struct A { ~A() { } int a; };
assert(A().a == 0);
```

Since you cannot do `A a()` (creates a function declaration instead), boost has a class [`value_initialized`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/utility/value_init.htm), allowing to work around that, and C++1x will have the following, alternative, syntax

```
int a{};
```

In the dry words of the Standard, this sounds like

> The expression T(), where T is a simple-type-specifier (7.1.5.2) for a non-array complete object type or the (possibly cv-qualified) void type, creates an rvalue of the specified type, which is value-initialized

Since a typedef-name is a type-name, which is a simple-type-specifier itself, this works just fine.

Comment: I've been poring over the draft standard trying to figure this out.  I'd forgotten about the typedef and was trying to figure out how a pointer type could be a simple-type-specifier (it's not), and now it makes sense: you can't do  int*(), but you can do T() if T is typedef'ed to int*.

Comment: What about non POD type and POD members?

Comment: struct A { ~A() { } int a; }; is a non-pod type. Had you introduced a constructor yourself, then the value of "a" depends on what that constructor does, of course.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
struct Foo {
    char bar;
    char baz;
    char foobar;
    // the struct is a POD
    //virtual void a() { bar='b'; }
};

int main() {
    Foo o1;
    Foo o2 = Foo();

    std::cout << "O1: " << (int)o1.bar <<" "<< (int)o1.baz <<" "<< (int)o1.foobar << std::endl;
    std::cout << "O2: " << (int)o2.bar <<" "<< (int)o2.baz <<" "<< (int)o2.foobar << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> O1: -27 -98 0
>
> O2: 0 0 0

Adding () propagates initializer calls to all POD members. Uncomenting the virtual method changes output to:

> O1: -44 -27 -98
>
> O2: -71 -120 4

However adding destructor ~Foo() does not suppress the initialization, although it creates non-POD object (output similar to first one).