# When to use () with classes?

Tags: c++, function, linked-list

This is really starting to confuse the hell out of me. When do I use them, when don't I?

For example I was reading a .cpp on linked lists whose class declaration was:

```
struct CarPart
{
    long PartNumber;
    char Partname[40];
    double UnitPrice;

    CarPart *next;
};

class ListOfParts
{
    int size;

public:
    CarPart *head;

    ListOfParts();
    ~ListOfParts();

    const int count() const;
    void insert( CarPart *item );
    CarPart *retrieve( int pos );
};
```

With this code, why am I allowed to write

```
ListOfParts *pPart = new ListOfParts();
CarPart *pCarPart = new CarPart;
```

Declaring an instance of ListOfParts requires (), but not my CarPart? That's confusing me. When I asked a question before and people told me that such a declaration is a function that returns a ListOfParts object, but not the actual constructor. So I'm guessing this is still something different.

What's happening here?

PS: Am I correct to assume that the const to the right of count() means I cannot modify any values in count?

Comment: Duplicate of [Do the parentheses after the type name make a difference with new?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Declaring an instance of `ListOfParts` class does not require `()` when allocating on the heap. Both forms are valid:

```
ListOfParts *pPart1 = new ListOfParts();
ListOfParts *pPart2 = new ListOfParts;
```

**EDIT:** *As the commenters have pointed out, [it makes a difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906734/does-c-do-value-initialization-of-a-pod-typedef) when initialising a [POD type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure)* (however is's not relevant to your code sample).

However, when declaring a stack variable or a static variable, it matters, because the form with `()` is the same as declaring a function.

```
ListOfParts pPart1(); // a function prototype
ListOfParts pPart2; // a object construction
```

`const` to the right of `count()` means you cannot modify any values *inside the current object* in this function, which will be `this->size` and `this->head` (note, you can still change object *pointed to* by `head`).

Comment: So there is nothing different between the two? Nothing at all?

Comment: @SoulBeaver, nothing whatsoever.

Comment: There is a difference for POD types -- the version with parentheses will zero-initialize the object.

Comment: It does.  Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/906734/does-c-do-value-initialization-of-a-pod-typedef

Comment: @avakar, the more you know...   I retract my clearly uninformed statement. Long live collective knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

As it was written you can use both version with and without `()`:

```
ListOfParts *pPart = new ListOfParts();
```

is equivalent to:

```
ListOfParts *pPart = new ListOfParts;
```

*Shamelessly copied from other answer: Excep POD*

The modifier `const` in declaration means that:

1. You cannot modify any variable of this class unless it was declared as `mutable`.
2. You can call it this method when the object is `const`.

Try:

```
#include <iostream>

class test
{
     void testf() {
          std::cout << "void test();" << std::endl;
     }

     void testf() const {
          std::cout << "void test() const;" << std::endl;
     }
 };

 int main() {
      test t;
      t.testf();
      const test &t2 = t;
      t2.testf();
 }
```

Comment: illegal function-style cast. This might be pretty insightful, but I'm not entirely sure what you're doing. How can you call test itself as a method for an object of test? Furthermore, both are giving me that error I mentioned. Is this normal?

Comment: Fixed. Sorry - I made a small spelling mistake which I fixed on disk but I haven't 'port' here.

Answer (score 1):

As for your post scriptum: yes, that means when you call `count()` on a `ListOfParts` instance, you cannot modify any instance member variables. Except when they are declared `mutable`.